# How to get a list of elements with Watin?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, watin

I'm trying to use Watin for testing. And I need to get a list of elements with specific properties, e.g. all links that have "Go" title.

I was trying this:

```
browser.Link(link => link.Text == "Go");
```

but it returns only one element.
Also I was trying this:

```
var links = from link in browser.Elements
                    where link.Text == "Go"
                    select link;
```

but this returns nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Filter` like: `browser.Links.Filter(Find.ByText("Go"));`

Answer (score 0):

Using Filter is a great way to go but if you wanted to use linq, you could use:

browser.Links.Where(link => link.Text == "Go");

-The reason it was returning one link for you was because you used a singular 'Link' not the plural 'Links' :)